# jQuery onClick action doesn't trigger second time

Tags: jquery, onclick

Based on a question answered earlier on SO, I've make this script which adds a CSS class to an element onClick. The problem is that it only works one time. How do I reset the function?

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.close-button').click(function(){
    jQuery(".content-display").addClass("cover");
    jQuery(".close-button").addClass("cover");
});

jQuery('.project').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content-display').addClass("uncover");
    jQuery('.close-button').addClass("uncover");
    }); 
});
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p2Av/) with everything.

Comment: what do you mean "reset the function"?

Comment: I mean, how to do I make the script to work every time, not just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove alternative class on action. After you press both close and project in your current code, you have both cover and uncover classes

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('.close-button').click(function(){
       jQuery(".content-display").addClass("cover").removeClass("uncover");
       jQuery(".close-button").addClass("cover").removeClass("uncover");
   });

   jQuery('.project').click(function(){
       jQuery('.content-display').addClass("uncover").removeClass("cover");
       jQuery('.close-button').addClass("uncover").removeClass("cover");
   }); 
 });
```

For this particular case usage of uncover class seems to be unnecessary, I vote for simple removeClass solution (@Stuart Feldt)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead:

```
jQuery('.project').click(function(){
        jQuery('.content-display').toggleClass("cover");
        jQuery('.close-button').toggleClass("cover");
    }); 
});
```

This way, if the class is already there, it will be removed; otherwise, it will be added. Also, you should toggle the `cover` class, since the `div`s are initially visible.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v32B7/)**.

Comment: Should remove the uncover class when clicking the X button as well.

Comment: Toggle works only if you have symmetrical action. If you do not want project info button to both hide and unhide - you cannot use toggle

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to hide and show the div, you can try:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.close-button').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(".content-display").addClass("cover");
        jQuery(".close-button").addClass("cover");
    });

    jQuery('.project').on('click', function(){    
        jQuery(".content-display").removeClass("cover");
        jQuery(".close-button").removeClass("cover");
    }); 
});
```